# How to create a multi page alert dialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am planning to create a questionnaire with the help of Alert dialogs, But I am not sure how to approach it, how to transition from one dialog to another with the previous answers.

e.g. 
first dialog says enter your name and presents a TextFormField, with two actions below, cancel and next. Tapping on next creates another dialog and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a variable to save status current dialog. After click button "Next", you will change value of variable and update UI on current dialog